# Timers and LEDs in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a question about using timers and clocks in Verilog. I want to set up a custom reg to compare to an accumulator, which will control the state of an LED. The board uses inverse logic, so 0 is high on the LED. There are a few concepts I just need some clarification on. The clock is 100 MHz.

```
always @(posedge clk100 or negedge reset_)
  begin
    cust_LED_counter    <= (cust_LED_counter<cust_LED_timer) ? cust_LED_counter + 1'b1 : 16'd0;
    cust_LED_timer1 <= (cust_LED_counter == cust_LED_timer);
    if(!reset_)
        begin
            cust_LED1   <= 'b0;
            cust_LED_timer <= 'd0;
            cust_LED_timer1 <= 'd0;
        end
    else
        begin
            cust_LED1 <= ~cust_LED_timer1;
        end
end
```

For the accumulator, what is the action that resets it and allows for blinking to happen? Would it not hit the `cust_LED_timer` value and stay at that high reading?

I think I'm misunderstanding how a FPGA clock operates. Assuming this would cause a blinking action in the LED, it would mean some timer hit the upper limit and reset; however, I'm not sure if this would take place in the counter portion of the code, or instead would occur where the clock/reset is defined.

Also, based on how this layout looks it wouldn't be a uniform blink, in terms of equal time on and off. Is there a way to implement such a system for custom input?

Comment: I'm not sure the `begin`/`end` pairs are valid.

Comment: I agree, and wouldn't it also be easier to implement an arbitrary int (lets call it N) counter with an `always_ff` and then switch the LED based upon `count <= N/2` within an `always_comb`? Assuming you can use system verilog.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I believe I fixed those pairing. I'm still trying to pick Verilog up though so they could still be mismatched.

Comment: @IanGraham For that solution, would I implement the reset outside of that loop for initialization? And I think I would be that arbitrary N, assuming it can be set as a reg. I was aiming to set it as a dictionary value that could be altered to meet different timings.

Comment: start with simulation of your design.

Comment: @Serge Just ran a simulation of the code above, had some errors with my `begin`/`end` commands, I am getting a different error with always loop. [This](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_veri_if_condition_does_not_match_sensitivity_list_edge.htm) is the Quartus page for the new issue that came up.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple module that should blink the LED with a 50-50 duty cycle for an arbitrary number of clocks (up to 2^26)

```
module blink(input clk, input rst, input [25:0] count_max, output LED);
    reg [25:0] counter, next_count;

    assign LED = counter < count_max >> 1;

    always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
    begin
        if (rst) 
            counter <= 0;
        else
            counter <= next_count;
    end

    always @* begin
        if (counter < count_max - 1)
            next_count = counter + 1;
        else
            next_count = 0;
    end
endmodule // blink
```

Let me know if this doesn't compile! I don't have a verilog compiler where I'm writing this from at the moment!

Comment: 'always' with no sensitivity list is a  recipe for trouble.

Comment: Don't most compilers infer it from the contents of the block?

Comment: all simulations will hang in there. No idea what synthesis would do. Try 'always @*' instead.

Comment: Ah, I may just be more used to using `always_comb` in system verilog that I know for sure does just fine without the sensitivity list. Thanks!

Comment: Just had to tweak the code a bit to meet the variables I had already assigned, but am getting a 10200 error here as well when compiling in Quartus. [This](https://imgur.com/a/WRyfDAW) is the modified code I posted. I'm not certain how to tie in a new module, so I was tying it into an existing one.

Comment: Definitely remove the `initial` block, I know for a fact that quartus doesn't support it.